# Prove $\sin(2\pi/7) +\sin(4\pi/7) +\sin(8\pi/7) = \sqrt7/2$

Tags: trigonometry

### Prove $$ \sin(2\pi/7) +\sin(4\pi/7) +\sin(8\pi/7) = \sqrt7/2$$

I have squared both sides and have come to the stage where the LHS is as follows

$$3/2 -1/2 (\cos{4\pi/7} + \cos{8\pi/7} + \cos{16\pi/7})$$

How do  I get it to equal 7/4

PS; I DO NOT KNOW ANYTHING ABOUT COMPLEX NUMBERS

Answer (score 3):

Let put $7\theta$=$2n\pi$ where $n$ stands for any integer.
Now $$7\theta=2n\pi$$$$4\theta=2n\pi-3\theta$$$$\Rightarrow \sin(4\theta)=\sin(2n\pi-3\theta)$$ $$\rightarrow \sin(4\theta)=-\sin(3\theta)\tag1$$

Now from equation $1$ we can get

$$2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)=4\sin^3\theta-3\sin\theta$$
$$4\sin\theta \cos\theta (1-2\sin^2\theta)=\sin\theta(4\sin^2\theta-3)$$
$$4\cos\theta(1-2\sin^2\theta)=4\sin^2\theta-3$$
Squaring both sides and then adding the result, you will get
$$64\sin^6\theta-112\sin^4\theta+56\sin^2\theta-7=0$$

This is a cubic with $\sin^2\theta$ with the roots:$\sin^2(2\pi /7)$, $\sin^2(4\pi /7)$, $\sin^2(8\pi /7)$

Sum of the roots is $$\sin^2(2\pi /7)+\sin^2(4\pi /7)+\sin^2(8\pi /7)=\frac{7}{4}\tag2$$

But you can prove through trigonometric identities (as sum of all the angles is $2\pi$) that 
$$\sin(2\pi /7) \sin(4\pi /7)+\sin(4\pi /7) \sin(8\pi /7)+\sin(2\pi /7)\sin(8\pi /7)=0$$

Hence the sum of the roots from $(2)$
$$(\sin(2\pi /7)+\sin(4\pi /7)+\sin(8\pi /7))^2=\frac{7}{4}$$
And the result follows.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that the roots are$$sin^2(2\pi /7),sin^2(4\pi /7),sin^2(8\pi /7)$$

Comment: @sidt36  Because $\theta=2n\pi /7$

Comment: Ah....Finally I get it...But Why can't it be $\sin^2 10\pi/7$ or any other even multiple of $\pi/7$

Comment: @sidt36 Ya you are right it can be. For example check out for $20\pi /7, 10\pi /7$, it would surely give the result. I just use the starting three to get my work done.

Comment: @Harsh Sharma 
"But you can prove through trigonometric identities (as sum of all the angles is $2\pi$) that 
$$\sin(2\pi /7) \sin(4\pi /7)+\sin(4\pi /7) \sin(8\pi /7)+\sin(2\pi /7)\sin(8\pi /7)=0$$" how can u show it ? I did differently and it was lengthy